# Select user id with specific condition

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I select LINK_USER_ID who has only 1 CA account and 1 SA account. There are users which have 2 CA and 1 SA or 1 CA only or 1 SA only using SQL query.

NOTE: 1 LINK_USER_ID can linked to multi LINK_CIS_NO.

Sample data

| LINK_ODDS_NO | LINK_ACCT_NO | LINK_USER_ID | LINK_CIS_NO | LINK_ACCT_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 124770648 | 3180879599940 | 99134982 | 3236463 | CA |
| 124770649 | 3180879599941 | 99134982 | 3236464 | SA |
| 124770650 | 3180879599942 | 99134981 | 3236465 | CA |
| 124770651 | 3180879599943 | 99134981 | 3236466 | SA |
| 124770652 | 3180879599944 | 99134984 | 3236455 | MC |
| 124770653 | 3180879599945 | 99134984 | 3236478 | CA |
| 124770654 | 3180879599946 | 99134985 | 32364688 | CA |
| 124770655 | 3180879599947 | 99134985 | 3236556 | SA |
| 124770656 | 3180879599948 | 99134986 | 3244879 | SA |

Expected result

| LINK_USER_ID |
| --- |
| 99134982 |

Comment: Why only 99134982? As far as I can see, all LINK_USER_ID (except the last one, 99134986) satisfy the condition: "who has only 1 CA account and 1 SA account". How does note ("1 LINK_USER_ID can linked to multi LINK_CIS_NO") affect the result?

Comment: [Previous version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74085919/266304) (now deleted) for reference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate by id and count conditionally:

```
select link_user_id
from mytable
group by link_user_id
having count(case when link_acct_type = 'CA' then 1 end) = 1
   and count(case when link_acct_type = 'SA' then 1 end) = 1`.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select LINK_USER_ID
from table
where LINK_ACCT_TYPE in ('CA', 'SA')
group by LINK_USER_ID
having count(distinct LINK_ACCT_TYPE) = 2
```

The query groups the data by LINK_USER_ID and then checks to see if there are two distinct values for LINK_ACCT_TYPE (CA and SA). If there are, then that LINK_USER_ID is included in the results.

Comment: thank you bro, but it doesn't  work properly there's an LINK_USER_ID that retrieve with this query has multi SA AND CA account i need only to retrieve the LINK_USER_ID that linked with1 CA account and 1 SA account.